# C# calculator that adds numbers together

Tags: c#, string, calculator

I want to add two strings together like a calculator, not next to each other.
This is my code:

```
        void MainAdd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string Add1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string Add2 = Console.ReadLine();
            string add = Add1 + Add2;
            Console.WriteLine(add);
            startcode();
        }
```

How can I make it work like a calculator?

Comment: Looks like you’re adding two strings together instead of two numbers. Try converting the strings to numbers before adding them.

Comment: you need to read a tutorial about different datatypes. `string` is for representing a sequence of `chars` (characters) what you need is a datatype that represents numbers like `int`, `double` etc

Comment: [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-data-types) and [this one](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2142910&seqNum=6) should get you started. sorry mate but I will vote to close this question for the lack of research. Google would have provided you all the answers that you need if you type in the title of your question

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double add1 = InputValue("Input first addend");
    double add2 = InputValue("Input second addend");

    double sum = add1 + add2;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum);
}

static double InputValue(string message)
{
    double value;
    string input;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (!double.TryParse(input, out value));

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [built in types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types), you can't do *numerical operations* on `string` (text):

```
int Add1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int Add2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int add = Add1 + Add2;
Console.WriteLine(add);
```

Also, this was just an example, you should never trust the user to enter the right thing, Use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

```
int add = Int32.Parse(Add1) + Int32.Parse(Add2);
Console.WriteLine(add);
```